# TS.ED and Prisma TS2322: Type UserModel is not assignable to type In

Tags: node.js, typescript, prisma

Got that error after using new TS.ED and Prisma. I suspect there is something wrong in the model generation for relationship.

here is the schema for prisma

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,

// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator tsed {
  provider = "tsed-prisma"
}

model User {
  /// @TsED.Groups("!creation")
  id    String     @default(uuid()) @id
  email String  @unique
  name  String
  password String
  /// @TsED.Groups('!creation')
  companies CompaniesOnUsers[]
  /// @TsED.Groups('!creation')
  createdById   String?
  /// @TsED.Groups('!creation')
  createdBy     User? @relation("CreateHistory", fields: [createdById], references: [id])
  /// @TsED.Groups('!creation')
  createdUser   User[] @relation("CreateHistory")
  /// @TsED.Groups('!creation')
  createdAt     DateTime @default(now())
  /// @TsED.Groups('!creation')
  updatedAt     DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Company {
  /// @TsED.Groups("!creation")
  id    String     @default(uuid()) @id
  name  String
  /// @TsED.Groups('!creation')
  users CompaniesOnUsers[]
  /// @TsED.Groups('!creation')
  createdAt     DateTime @default(now())
  /// @TsED.Groups('!creation')
  updatedAt     DateTime @updatedAt
}

model CompaniesOnUsers {
  user      User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    String // relation scalar field (used in the `@relation` attribute above)
  company   Company @relation(fields: [companyId], references: [id])
  companyId String // relation scalar field (used in the `@relation` attribute above)
  assignedAt DateTime @default(now())
  assignedBy String

  @@id([userId, companyId])
}
```

and the code error in the controller

```
@Post("/")
  @Returns(201, UserModel)
  async create(@BodyParams() @Groups("creation") user: UserModel): Promise<UserModel> {
    user.password = await this.service.hashPassword(user.password);
    return this.repository.create({data: user});
```

here is the complete error message on the data part

> TS2322: Type  UserModel  is not assignable to type
> (Without<UserCreateInput, UserUncheckedCreateInput> &
> UserUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & UserCreateInput) Type
>  UserModel  is not assignable to type
> Without<UserUncheckedCreateInput, UserCreateInput> & UserCreateInput
> Type  UserModel  is not assignable to type
> Without<UserUncheckedCreateInput, UserCreateInput> Types of property
>  createdById  are incompatible. Type  string | null  is not assignable
> to type  undefined  Type  null  is not assignable to type  undefined 
> index.d.ts(1950, 5): The expected type comes from property  data 
> which is declared here on type  UserCreateArgs